# How to stop zoom chat scroll bar from disappearing?

Tags: zoom.us

When I teach over Zoom, I have a small chat window on the side.  It is very difficult to use because the vertical scrollbar keeps disappearing.  I have to fidget with the size of the window in order to make the scroll bar appear, then I must move my cursor fast enough to grab the scroll bar before it disappears.  Very frustrating.

My mac laptop had a similar "feature" of scroll bar disappearance,  but I found a way to configure my laptop to keep the scroll bars.  I do not know how to do it for the Zoom-generated chat box.